# Which levels contain Failure Logs?

Tags: infinifactory

Some levels in Infinifactory contain so-called *Failure Logs*, which are 30s to 2min audio clips which provide a bit of background story. They are usually (but not always) found in the form of a dead person in a spacesuit. It appears that not every level contains such a Failure Log, but most of them do. Still, I was surprised by the scarcity of the logs in two level sets, so I was wondering if I just overlooked them or whether they really appear this irregularly.

Curiously, I wasn't able to find a complete list of the logs online, so here we go: which levels contain a Failure Log and what does it look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following levels contain Failure Logs:

**Proving Grounds**

- Training Routing 3
- Training Routine 4
- Training Routine 5

**Skydock 19**

- Munitions Refill Type 6
- Shuttle Proportion Units
- Guided Javelin Type 1

**Resource Site 526.81**

- Optical Sensor Array Type 2
- Landing Alignment Lights
- Optical Sensor Array Type 4
- Small Excavator
- Cargo Uplifter

**Production Zone 2**

- Shuttle Maintenance
- Furnished Studio Apartment

**Resource Site 338.11**

- Guided Javelin Type 2
- Gneiss Chair
- Relay Satellite
- Terrestrial Surveyor
- Anti-Javelin Point Defense

**Resource Site 902.42**

- Terrestrial Drone
- Ariel Combat Shuttle